# How to use custom axis ticks on Bokeh?

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I tried to specify x and y axis ticks on Bokeh plot as [0,25,50,75,100] and try major_label_overrides x as distance {0:'alone(0)',25: 'not close(25)', 50: 'alright close(50)', 75: 'middle close(75)', 100:'very close(100)'},  y axis custom as frequency {0:'never',25: 'once a year', 50: 'once a month', 75: 'once a week', 100:'everyday(100)'}. However, it shows an error. Thank you.

> ValueError: expected an instance of type Ticker, got [25, 50, 75, 100]
>   of type list

I have tried 
p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=[0, 25, 50,75,100]) 
it fixes the tick problem but I can't customise it to frequency.

Below is my code and github repository. 
https://github.com/Lastget/Covid19_Job_risks.git

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Label, LabelSet
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer
from math import pi
from bokeh.models import FixedTicker

# Improt files
expose = pd.read_csv(r'Exposed_to_Disease_or_Infections.csv',encoding='gbk')
expose.head() #context, code, occupation 
expose.shape #(968,3)

physical = pd.read_csv('Physical_Proximity.csv')
physical.head()
physical.shape #(967,3)

TW_job = pd.read_excel('Small_Chinese.xlsx',encoding='utf-8')
TW_job.shape #(968,3)
TW_job = TW_job.iloc[:,:2]
TW_job.head()

#Merge
temp_df = pd.merge(expose,physical,on=['Code','Occupation'])
temp_df.head()
temp_df.columns=['Expose_frequency','Code','Occupation','Physical_proximity']
temp_df.head()
full_table = temp_df.merge(TW_job,how='left',on='Code')
full_table.shape #967,5

# Delete Expose frequency for Rock splitter, timing deivce 
full_table = full_table.iloc[:965,:]

# change expose  to int64 
full_table['Expose_frequency']=full_table['Expose_frequency'].astype('int64')
full_table.info()

# Start plotting 
source = ColumnDataSource(full_table) 
p = figure(title="各職業對新型冠狀病毒之風險圖", x_axis_label='工作時與人接近程度', y_axis_label='工作時暴露於疾病頻率',
          plot_width=900, plot_height=600)
p.circle('Physical_proximity','Expose_frequency',
          name = 'allcircle',
          size=10,fill_alpha=0.2, source=source, fill_color='gray', hover_fill_color='firebrick', hover_line_color="firebrick", line_color=None)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('職業','@TW_Occupation'),('Occupation','@Occupation'),('暴露於疾病指數','@Expose_frequency'),('與人接近距離指數','@Physical_proximity')])
p.add_tools(hover)


p.xaxis.ticker = [0, 25, 50,75,100]
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {0:'獨自工作(0)',25: '不近(25)', 50: '稍微近(50)', 75: '中等距離(75)', 100:'非常近(100)'}
p.yaxis.ticker = [0, 25, 50,75,100]
p.yaxis.major_label_overrides = {0:'從不(0)',25: '一年一次(25)', 50: '一個月一次(50)', 75: '一週一次(75)', 100:'每天(100)'}
p.yaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4

# remove tool bar 
p.toolbar.logo = None
p.toolbar_location = None

def remove_glyphs(figure, glyph_name_list):
    renderers = figure.select(dict(type=GlyphRenderer))
    for r in renderers:
        if r.name in glyph_name_list:
            col = r.glyph.y
            r.data_source.data[col] = [np.nan] * len(r.data_source.data[col])


# Define a callback function 
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
       remove_glyphs(p,['point_select'])
       old_choice=full_table[full_table['TW_Occupation']==old]  

       choice=full_table[full_table['TW_Occupation']==new]
       a=choice['Physical_proximity']
       b=choice['Expose_frequency']
       p.circle(a,b,size=10,fill_alpha=1,fill_color=None,line_color="firebrick", name='point_select')

# Add Select 
select = Select(title='請選擇工作', options=sorted(full_table['TW_Occupation'].tolist()), value='')

# Attach the update_plot callback to the 'value' property of select
select.on_change('value', update_plot)

#layout 
layout = row(p, select)

# Add the plot to the current document
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Your code (the particular section that deals with the axes) works just fine for me with Bokeh 2.0.0.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Thank you! I found out that I my Bokeh version somehow switched to an older version ... Weird . Thanks alot!